# VMWare Fusion ungrab mouse and keyboard command triggers android home

Tags: vmware-fusion, android-x86

I've got an x86 android image loaded into VMWare fusion.  When I select the keys for ungrabbing the mouse and keyboard, the command key triggers the home button and whatever app I'm in gets pushed to the background.

Is there way to remap either the ungrab hot key or the home button so that this conflict doesn't occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the keyboard settings, if you remap the Windows key to the right command button, you can then use the left command button to release the mouse without triggering the home key response.

Comment: You deserve so much more for answering your own question.  Two and a half-years later, I needed this.  I shall name my next domain controller after your gloriousness.

Comment: haha, that comment made my day.